# La cola de revisión de reapertura no se llena correctamente

Tags: soporte, votos-de-reapertura, colas-de-revisión

Navegando por StackOverflow en Español,  me he encontrado con [una pregunta que está en espera](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63641/actualizar-una-grafica-sin-refrescar-la-pagina) (al momento de escribir este post), tiene 3 votos de reapertura, y sin embargo no aparece en las colas de revisión para reapertura.

Pensaba que si alguien votaba por reabrir una pregunta, esa pregunta aparecería en la cola de revisión de reapertura, pero ese no es el caso. ¿Es eso normal o es un error en el sitio?

Como nota: yo no soy uno de esos 3 votos de reapertura, ni he respondido a si quiero reabrir o no esa pregunta, ni he visitado la cola de revisión con anterioridad a ver los votos de reapertura. (Al menos, no que yo recuerde)

Captura de pantalla de la pregunta con 3 votos de reapertura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Captura de pantalla de las colas de revisión al mismo tiempo que la otra captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La publicación pasó por la cola de revisión: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/39964
y se definió "Dejar cerrada".

Los votos de reapertura persisten incluso después de terminada la revisión.

En cuanto a lo que corresponde en este caso, quizás se podría asistir mejor con un comentario, pero creo que la descripción del cierre por *demasiado amplia* aplica bien en este caso.

Comment: Gracias. Tenía que haber revisado el historial. Ya lo sé para la siguiente

Comment: Desde el [timeline](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/63641/timeline) se obtiene más rápido ;-) ... Igual, caí en la misma trampa miles de veces, me pasa todo el tiempo.

Comment: @mariano con [tu extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-overflow-timeline/omclkfdjappannhpjjngnnppfmidlbbh), timeline inmediato :D

Comment: @lois6b jaja, sí, pero escuché que el autor de esa extensión dejó algunas cosas pendientes y no da mucho soporte :-)

Comment: @mariano bobadas.. no tengo queja alguna ^^